# The movement of electrons in a section of a cable is from east to west, to which direction will a compass placed on this section of the cable point?

Tags: electromagnetism

This is high-school physics, and the answer is **"south"**. I cannot comprehend however why it would point to the south.
My understanding of the question is that it is asking for the direction of the magnetic field, for finding which my textbook has supplied me with the right-hand rule for a simple straight cable (as well as a solenoid and a ring).  However, since the direction of the magnetic field for a cable basically is always relative to a certain point x distance from the cable, I infer that I am not on the right track, if I am on any track at all.
The question title here is the question from my textbook verbatim (not after the site refused to post this question on account of it being more than 150 characters, but the essence is still there), with the exception of a little tip that says "electric current is discerned by the movement of the positive charges" (verbatim translation, the implications of which I can't actually comprehend).

Thanks for reading, thanks for answering, thanks and thanks for providing an answer that lets me comprehend this thing in its entirety.

Answer (score 0):

The magnetic field around an infinitely long wire are loops of circle around the wire. The strength depending on the distance from the wire.
[image]

You can proceed from here I’m sure.

Comment: In fact I know about this rule, the problem is that the direction is relative to a point, and in the question it simply says "a compass is placed on that section of the cable" without mentioning which side.

Comment: I would assume the side with respect to which the electrons are moving from east to west. Remember that north-south-east-west are all relative to your frame in this situation. But once you fix a convention (in this case by the motion of the electrons) you stick to that frame.

Comment: How do I know with respect to which side the electrons are moving from east to west?

Comment: It sort of seems to me that this question lacks some essential information?

Comment: Assign an arbitrary direction for the flow of the electron, that is now east to west. It has nothing to do with the geographical east or west. But once you have assigned the east and west, north and south are fixed. Let’s say you stand in front of the wire and see that the electrons are moving from right to left, then your left hand points to west and right hand points to east. Head points to north and legs to south. Now you place a compass between you and the wire, which direction will it point? The question would lose some of its ambiguity with a figure.